# Does approximately Fréchet differentiable imply approximately Gateaux differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

In what follows, $\mu^n$ denotes $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, and $B_r(x)$ is the open ball with radius $r$ centered at $x$.

---

In elementary calculus, if we have a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ which is Fréchet differentiable at a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $f$ is automatically Gateaux differentiable at $p$ also.

However in geometric measure theory, we have the notion of approximate limits and differentiability. The definitions are valid as long as $f$ is a measurable function, and are given as follows:

> 1. $f$ is approximately Fréchet differentiable at $p$ if there exists a linear map $L : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, such that for all $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$: $$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\mu^n(\{x \in B_r(p) : \frac{|f(x) - f(p) - L(x-p)|}{|x-p|} > \varepsilon \})}{\mu^n(B_r(p))} = 0 $$

> 2. $f$ is approximately Gateaux differentiable at $p$ if for all unit vectors $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists $L_u \in \mathbb{R}^m$, such that for all $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$: $$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\mu^1(\{t \in (-r,r) : |\frac{f(p+tu) - f(p)}{t} - L_u| > \varepsilon \})}{2r} = 0 $$

Notice that here approximately Gateaux differentiable means that **all** the approximate directional derivatives exist, not just almost all of them. In fact it is this distinction which prevents Fréchet necessarily implying Gateaux pointwise.

---

Now my question is, what if we have everywhere approximately differentiable and not just pointwise? Specifically, if $f$ is everywhere approximately Fréchet differentiable, is $f$ necessarily approximately Gateaux differentiable?

For what it's worth, given any fixed unit vector $u$, it's known that the approximate $u$-directional derivative exists almost everywhere (see theorem 2 here https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Approximate_differentiability). My question is equivalent to asking if this can be extended to existing everywhere, once we have everywhere approximately Fréchet differentiable?

Comment: "In fact it is this distinction which prevents Fréchet necessarily implying Gateaux pointwise [...] Now my question is, what if we have everywhere approximately differentiable and not just pointwise?" I'm a bit confused...aren't "pointwise" and "everywhere" synonymous? For me solving pointwise an ODE, for instance, means solving it classically at every point (and not just weakly).

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The pointwise statement would be "$f$ is A.F.D. at $x$ implies $f$ is A.G.D. at $x$" vs the everywhere statement of "$f$ is A.F.D. everywhere on its domain implies $f$ is A.G.D. everywhere on its domain".

If I'm still not being clear, take the difference between the statements "$f$ is $0$ at $x$ implies $f'$ is $0$ at $x$" vs "$f$ is everywhere $0$ implies $f'$ is everywhere $0$".

Answer (score 2):

I have an example which does not strictly answer the question, but a slightly weaker one.

> **Theorem 1.** There is a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ that is approximately Fréchet differentiable almost everywhere, but $f$ is approximately Gateaux differentiable on a set of measure zero.

The construction is based on the existence of Nikodym sets:

> **Theorem 2.** (Nikodym) There is a Borel set $N\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\mu^2(N)=0$ and for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ there is a line $L$ though $x$ for which $L\setminus\{x\}\subset N$.

This is Theorem 11.7 in Mattila's "Fourier Analysis and Hausdorff Dimension".

*Proof of Theorem 1.* Let $A=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus N$ and let $f=\chi_A$ be the characteristic function of $A$. Since the complement of $A$ has measure zero, $f$ is approximately Fréchet differentiable at every point of $A$ with $Df=0$.
On the other hand if $x\in A$ and $L$ is the linie form Theorem 1, then the function $f$ restricted to that line equals $1$ at $x$ and zero everywhere else so it is not approximately differentiable in the direction of $L$ and hence $f$ is not approximately Gateaux differentiable at any point $x\in A$.   $\Box$

Comment: Thank you for this reply. Unfortunately it is not quite what I am looking for as you are aware, but I still appreciate this input.